# Need help clarifying relation properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

So I am facing some issues determining the right properties for: $ xRy\;if\,\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(y) = 1 $. (On real numbers)

Obviously this one is reflexive as $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1 $ is a basic trigonometric identity. Where I'm blocking though is when I try to determine if it's symmetric, antisymmetric and transitive.

I kind of have the feeling that it is symmetric since when $(a,b)$ is part of the relation, so is $(b,a)$ (as long as $a=b$). This would also mean it is antisymmetric. And finally it should be transitive since the only $(x,y)$ couples that this relation takes are couples where $x=y$ and therefore $y = z$.

The answer apparently is what I just said except for the antisymmetric part (according to my TA). I was wondering what it is that I am not getting about the asymmetry part.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning for transitive is wrong because $\sin(0)^2+\cos(2\pi)^2=1$ and $0 \ne 2\pi$. Just expand the definition of transitivity of $R$ on $\mathbb{C}$ as follows.

For any $x,y,z \in \mathbb{C}$:

If $x R y$ and $y R z$:

... [Expand the definition of $x R y$ and $y R z$ here.]

... [Manipulate what you have here until you get the definition of $x R z$.]

$x R z$

Therefore $R$ is transitive on $\mathbb{C}$

Same for symmetric:

For any $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$:

If $x R y$:

... [Expand the definition of $x R y$ here.]

... [Manipulate what you have here until you get the definition of $y R x$.]

$y R x$

Therefore $R$ is symmetric on $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Thank you very much! Hadn't considered 0 and $2\pi$. I also suppose that having $(0,2\pi)$ and $(2\pi,0)$ makes this relation non-antisymmetrical then?

Comment: Right, $R$ is not antisymmetric because of such a counter-example.